# How can I use promise.all to return after multiple if statements in ES6/Typescript/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a storage load function that I'd like to have a promise for and in this function I need to load several items from the device and wait until all have finished before resolving.

The current function for loading returns a promise that has the data loaded from storage.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
Init(){
    platform.ready()
        .then(() => this.platformTest())
        .then(() => this.otherTest())
        .then(() => this.anotherTest()
        .then(() => this.storageLoad())
        .catch(error => console.log(error);
}

storageLoad(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (this.platform == 'android'){
            //do android specific stuff
        }
        if (this.platform == 'ios'){
            //do ios specific stuff
        }
        storage.get(x)
        .then(data => this.x = data);
        storage.get(y)
        .then(data => this.y = data);
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to wait until all of these have loaded or where to put the resolve function. I've tried googling, but I'm having a hard time understanding ES6 promises.

Any light shined on the topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: But you already wrote in the title of your question that you can use `Promise.all` for that.

Comment: I'm looking for how to do that, I don't understand or can't find examples.

Comment: Try `Promise.all([storage.get(x).then(...), storage.get(y).then(...)]).then(resolve, reject);`

Comment: But why do you store the data in `this`? Why not resolve the promise with the data instead?

Comment: Because this.x isn't actually this.x, I just didn't want to add more code that I thought was necessary. 

I'm storing all the data returned in a shared service between all my typescript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` (simplified) works like this: You pass it an array of Promises. Let's call them "input Promises". And it returns a new Promise – an "output Promise".

(Technically you don't have to pass an array which does also not have to contain Promises, but that's a not too important implementation detail here.)

If all input Promises are successfully resolved, the output Promise gets resolved with an array containing the values of the resolved input Promises.

If any of the passed input Promises fails, the output Promise gets rejected.

---

I assume your question is about your second method.

You don't actually need to run `new Promise` there. Instead, pass both of your storage method executions to `Promise.all()` and return that.

Because there's no `function` keyword, I assume this is from a class context. Would have made things easier to grasp if you had mentioned that.

```
storageLoad() {
  if (this.platform == 'android'){
    //do android specific stuff
  }
  if (this.platform == 'ios'){
    //do ios specific stuff
  }
  const storageX = storage.get(x)
    .then(data => this.x = data);
  const storageY = storage.get(y)
    .then(data => this.y = data);

  return Promise.all([ storageX, storageY ])
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

UPDATE:

To use Promises in `Promise.all()` conditionally, just build the array of Promises passed to it dynamically. Like this:

```
storageLoad() {
  // Create a new array with Promises
  const storageProcesses = [];

  if (this.platform == 'android'){
    //do android specific stuff
    storageProcesses.push(someAndroidSpecificStorageMethod());
  }
  if (this.platform == 'ios'){
    //do ios specific stuff
    storageProcesses.push(someIOSSpecificStorageMethod());
  }

  storageProcesses.push(storage.get(x)
    .then(data => this.x = data));
  storageProcesses.push(storage.get(y)
    .then(data => this.y = data));

  return Promise.all(storageProcesses)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to typescript, I'm not 100% familiar with what even the class context is. If I was loading something from storage inside my if statements, how would I go about including them in the Promise.all() statement at the bottom of your snippet?

Comment: Who is "them"? And: With "class context" I just meant that your functions are missing a `function` keyword. That usually only happens if they are methods inside a class.

Comment: Them in this context are the if statements I was referring to in the previous half of the sentence.

Comment: Oh, okay. Somehow overlooked the first half of your sentence. :) I added another example to my answer regarding that scenario.

Comment: Augie, remember that there are no 'classes' in the context of javascript. Everything is an object, including all functions and variables, with the exception of primitive values.

Comment: Except that this isn't pure javascript and the typescript compiler will get angry if you try to do some things.